# Manipulate ListPlot a matrix

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

i am tring to plot a propagating wave function, but the instead of function i have points.
so i have a n*n matrix (TTpsi) that i want to plot each row separately. 
The wave is "propagating" when the row number increase. 
The code i wrote is

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[{TTpsi[[k]], v}, PlotRange -> 1], {k, 1, 50}]
```

It does plot the TTpsi[[1]] correctly but it just send an error when trying to plot the rest.
I can plot each of them separately so i know that they each works on their own.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that `k` takes non-integer values.  Simply adding ",1" should fix it.

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[{TTpsi[[k]], v}, PlotRange -> 1], {k, 1, 50, 1}]
```

Comment: If you have another problem, please ask another question, rather than changing a question that already has an answer.